# How do I install OpenSSL in ElCaptain if my HomeBrew it's broken?

Tags: macos, homebrew, openssl

After an upgrade from 10.10 to 10.11, my rails environment was broken.

I've removed the broken open-source projects/files and now I'm trying to install HomeBrew.

But I receive this message:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
curl: (77) SSL: can't load CA certificate file /System/Library/OpenSSL/certs/cert.pem
```

But to install OpenSSL, I need homebrew. So, I'm stuck.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can curl without SSL by removing the ‘s’ from ‘https’:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Additionally, you could just point a web browser to the page, http://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install and save the code to `/tmp/brew.rb` as a text file and then run it

```
ruby -e /tmp/brew.rb
```

Comment: Hi @bmike. It worked! But,when I try to install OpenSSL following [this](https://solitum.net/openssl-os-x-el-capitan-and-brew/), it returns this message: https://gist.github.com/e210f21b90db0b5e4215

Comment: @Cleyton Good - so there's progress. I would start a new post with brew doctor output.

Comment: @bmike No need. I found the solution: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32065#issuecomment-54260865 . Thanks man!

Comment: Woah @Cleyton - I hope to live to see the day when environment variables can no longer cause this sort of pain.